# How can i use (WebElement webdriverWait till element is clickable) in method and call that method for re use

Tags: java, selenium, class, wait

As per my code below, i need to use Wait element regularly. Is there any way where as i can re use this code by calling method?

Any help or suggestion would be grateful.

public static By header = By.xpath("//*[@id=\'content\']/h1");

```
 public static void ClickLink_Accounts() throws IOException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    WebElement wait2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(header));
    find(Accounts).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver,"Application HomePage-");
}

public static void ClickLink_Tasks() throws IOException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    WebElement wait2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(header));
    find(Tasks).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver,"Application HomePage-");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this

```
public static void ClickLink_Accounts() throws IOException
{
    waitForHeader();
    find(Accounts).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver, "Application HomePage-");
}

public static void ClickLink_Tasks() throws IOException
{
    waitForHeader();
    find(Tasks).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver, "Application HomePage-");
}

public static void waitForHeader()
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(header));
}
```

But... when I look at your two ClickLink* methods, I see a lot of duplicated code. I would look for a way to combine those two (and maybe other future methods) into one that accepts a parameter. I'm assuming `Accounts` and `Tasks` are `By` locators since you are passing into a method `find()`? If so, you can do this

```
public static void ClickLink(By locator) throws IOException
{
    waitForHeader();
    find(locator).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver, "Application HomePage-");
}
```

and significantly simplify your code. See [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. this solve the issue. this was the issue as i have to reuse the same code again and again... which is not the best way...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
public static void ElementClickable(By selector, Object obj) throws IOException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    WebElement wait2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selector));
    find(obj).isDisplayed();
    CaptureScreenshot.Screenshot(driver,"Application HomePage-");
}
```